# Get WebPart Zone Information using Javascript - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, jsom, web-part-zone

I'm planning to get zone information of a web part using JSOM and I couldn't find any chance of getting it.

My Code:

```
var ctxOBJ = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var webOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_web();
var siteOBJ = ctxOBJ.get_site();
var pageURL = window.location.pathname;
var webPartManagerOBJ = webOBJ.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageURL).getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
  //get the web parts on the current page
  var collWebPart = webPartManagerOBJ.get_webParts();
  //request the web part collection and load it from the server
  ctxOBJ.load(collWebPart);
  ctxOBJ.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
    // Go through all webparts
    for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count(); x++) {
      debugger;
      var webPartDef = collWebPart.get_item(x);
      console.log(webPartDef.get_id().toString());
    }
  }), Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
    alert("failed to fetch shared webparts from page")
  }));
```

I need the zone id of each web part in that page.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ZoneId you'll have to use get_zoneId().

Change the load:

```
ctxOBJ.load(collWebPart,'Include(ZoneId)');
```

And the use get_zoneId():

```
console.log(webPartDef.get_zoneId());
```

If you plan to use props on the webpart itself, you'll have to load that too:

```
ctxOBJ.load(collWebPart,  'Include(WebPart.Title,WebPart.ZoneIndex, ZoneId)');
```

And then:

```
    console.log(webPartDef.get_zoneId());
    console.log(webPartDef.get_webPart().get_title());
    console.log(webPartDef.get_webPart().get_zoneIndex())
```

Comment: Can I get the property of webpart whether hidden or not?

Comment: @RealSteel you are probably thinking about if its closed or not? Then you have `webPartDef.get_webPart().get_isClosed()`, remember to add the prop to the load: `'Include(WebPart.IsClosed,WebPart.Title,WebPart.ZoneIndex, ZoneId)'`